# How does AND operation in Z80 cpu overflow?

Tags: cpu, flags, z80

I am referencing zilog z80 manual and i am little puzzled reading at AND instruction. It says in the 'condition bits affected' section, P/V flag is set if the operation overflows. I can understand how add or sub instruction overflows but it doesn't make sense for me that AND operation overflows. Any help is appreciated!! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.z80.info/z80sflag.htm), the P/V bit serves two purposes. The result for the AND instruction is really the P function, that is, the P bit is set if there are an even number of 1 bits in the result of doing the AND.

Comment: I am sorry if i missed it but is it written somewhere that parity P flag is affected during AND operation? Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, on the linked page, the line that reads `AND r                 SZ513P00`